# LINQ Contains statement behaves differently when used on a complex object to list of strings

Tags: c#, linq, moq

Am I being an idiot? Here's a Mocked repository:

```
Mock<IRepository> repMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
Quote q1 = new Quote { QuoteId = 123 };
Quote q2 = new Quote { QuoteId = 345 };
repMock.Setup(m => m.GetQuotes(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Quote, bool>>>())).Returns((new List<Quote> { q1, q2 }).AsQueryable);
```

Here's a LINQ statement which treats those Id's as strings, and fetches those which contain the string "3" (i.e both):

```
Assert.AreEqual(2, repMock.Object.GetQuotes(q => q.QuoteId.ToString().Contains("3")).Count());
```

Here's the same principal being applied to fetching just one string - but this fails. It returns both strings:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, repMock.Object.GetQuotes(q => q.QuoteId.ToString().Contains("1")).Count());
```

Yet if you pull the strings out into their own list and run contains against that, it works as expected:

```
List<string> foo = repMock.Object.GetQuotes(q => q.QuoteId.ToString().Contains("3")).Select(q => q.QuoteId.ToString()).ToList();
Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.Where(f => f.Contains("1")).Count());
```

What's going on here? This code seems to actually work in production and filters strings as expected - it only fails in the unit test?

EDIT: I see the logic in what @IvanStoev is saying here, that I'm setting the Mock to return a list of two objects regardless of the function passed in. So how can I get the test to honour the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
repMock.Setup(m => m.GetQuotes(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Quote, bool>>>()))
    .Returns((new List<Quote> { q1, q2 }).AsQueryable);
```

I'm not very familiar with the mockup frameworks, but it seems logically that you are setting up the `GetQuotes` function receiving a predicate to always return the whole list, ignoring the passed predicate, so that's why your test code always return 2 items.

**Update:** As per your edit, I guess you can use something like this

```
repMock.Setup(m => m.GetQuotes(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Quote, bool>>>()))
    .Returns((Expression<Func<Quote, bool>> predicate) => 
        (new List<Quote> { q1, q2 }).AsQueryable().Where(predicate));
```